# method does not replace all tags

Tags: java, regex

I have a class with 2 methods,one of them generates a regex that matches forbidden html tags,the other one scans a given input string for these tags:

```
private Pattern pattern;

private List<Pattern> generatePatterns(String[] blacklist)
{
    List<Pattern> deleteList = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
    for (String s : blacklist)
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)<((\\s|/)|(\\s,/))*?" + s + ".*?>");
        deleteList.add(pattern);
    }

    return deleteList;
}

public String cleanHTML(String unsafe, String[] blacklist)
{
    try
    {
        List<Pattern> gp = generatePatterns(blacklist);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(unsafe));
        String s;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            builder.append(s);
        }

        for (Pattern p : gp)
        {
            Matcher mat = p.matcher(builder.toString());
            if(mat.find()){
                builder.replace(mat.start(), mat.end(), "");
            }

        }
        return builder.toString();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
    }


}
```

I have tested it with this input:

```
String[] blacklist = new String[]
    { "img", "a", "script", "svg", "style", "link", "meta", "noscript", "code", "span", "div", "iframe", "object", "video", "source", "map", "area",
            "form", "onclick", "button" };
    String unsafe = "<p class='p1'>paragraph</p><img></img><Img><Script><Svg><a href><style><link><meta><noscript><code>"
            + "<span><div><iframe><object><video><audio><source><map><area><form><onclick><button>"
            + "< no html > <A href='#'>Link</A> <![CDATA[<sender>John Doe</sender>]]><a link=''>other link</a>";
```

But the output is:

```
<p class='p1'>paragraph</p></img><Img><audio>< no html > <A href='#'>Link</A> <![CDATA[<sender>John Doe</sender>]]><a link=''>otherlink</a>
```

So it basically matches most of the blacklisted tags,but not all of them.AND for some reason it does replace only 1 of 3  tags.I'm pretty sure that it has to do with my regex even though it has worked flawless before,now it does not match closing tags(e.g )anymore and it does not replace  and  tags for some reason.

---

If i change the method like that:

```
public String cleanHTML(String unsafe,String[] taglist){

        List<Pattern> gp = generatePatterns(taglist);

        for (Pattern p : gp)
        {
            Matcher mat = p.matcher(unsafe);
            unsafe = ((mat.find()) ? mat.replaceAll("") : unsafe);          

        }
        return unsafe;

}
```

it works,may have something to do with the buffered string then?Although it replaces most tags.Drives me insane.

Comment: See [why you shouldn't use regex for parsing HTML]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3811553)

Answer (score 1):

Never use Regex for parsing HTML, HTML structure can get very complex and it is not easy to implement a flawless regex for working with HTML. I recommend using a HTML parser library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

you can remove tags like this

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
document.select("img").unwrap(); //removes all <img> tags
document.select("p, a, img").unwrap(); //remove multiple tags
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip.I already heard of this library.The problem is that I can't use extern libraries,as this assignment was given to get a look at  regex